# SAS: dataset name Remove the date and replace with the current date

Tags: datetime, sas, sas-macro, sas-studio

I currently have a macro which moves my dataset from one branch to another. In each movement, the date is updated. However, I am having trouble with removing the old date autonomously before inputting the new date, any advice?

The code is:

```
%Macro Merge_Branch(Branch = , Filename = , Library = );

    %Let Timestamp = %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(date()),yymmddn8.));

    %if &Branch. = Latest_Commit %then %do;

        Data LC._&Timestamp._&Filename.;
        set &Library..&Filename.;
        run;

    %end;

    %else %if &Branch. = Staging %then %do;

        %Let Filename = _20180909_Financial_Input;
        %Let Filename_temp = %scan(&Filename.,2,'_');
                %Let Date_String = %scan(&Filename.,1,'_');
                /* this is the section where I get stuck the dash is a subtraction i.e. I want to remove the date and just have the string*/
        %Let Filename_Stg = &Filename_temp - &Date_String;

        Data Stg._&Timestamp._&Filename_Stg.;
        set LC.&Filename.;
        run;

    %end;

%mend;

Input data can be made like this

data LC._20180909_Financial_Input;
var var1;
datalines;
1
1
1
1
;
run;

%Macro Merge_Branch(Branch = Staging , Filename = Financial_Input, Library = LC );

/*Note, in this macro the library is not important because it will always move from LC to STG*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new file name is resolving to this.

```
Data Stg._20181009_Financial - 20180909;
```

That is not a SASNAME.

Comment: my original intention was to display my desire to subtract 20180909 from _20180909_Financial.

confusion due to my mislabelling and so on